# Can I make Ubuntu Desktop as my git server or I need to have a Ubuntu Server for it?

Tags: git

I am new to git. I want to set up a git server. But I am confused, should I make y Ubuntu Desktop machine as a git server or I will have to have Ubuntu Server for it. Or both will do.

Comment: You can install a git server on Ubuntu server or desktop. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ubuntu desktop as git server. Ubuntu server has some application for management server like ftp server, dhcp server, something like that. But also, you install these application in Ubuntu desktop.